# Ansible select and combine attributes from a dictionary

Tags: ansible

```
---
- name: Consolidate output
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    data_set_1:
      host1:
        field1: '1'
        field2: '2'
      host2:
        field3: '3'
        field4: '4'
      host3:
        field1: '1'
        field3: '3'
      host4:
        field5: '5'
        field6: '6'
    data_set_2:
      - host1
      - host2
      - host3
```

I just need to parse through both the data sets and build the list of fields and the value for hosts in data set 2.

For example,
data_set_2 has three hosts host1, 2 and 3.
Corresponding data from data_set_1 for host1, 2 and 3 is 
     host1:
        field1: '1'
        field2: '2'
      host2:
        field3: '3'
        field4: '4'
      host3:
        field1: '1'
        field3: '3'

From this, I just need to build the result like this.

```
result = {
  field1: "1",
  field2: "2",
  field3: "3",
  field4: "4"
}
```

How can I do this from ansible playbook?

Comment: Hi Anees, welcome to SO. This site is not a "write code for me" site; you will want to include the code you have tried and the error you are getting when you run it.

Comment: Hints to where to look at in the documentation for possible ways to solve your problem: [extracting values from containers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers), [unique filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters), [json_query filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) dictionaries in the loop of the list created by   [map and extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers). For example

```
- set_fact:
    result: "{{ result|default({})|combine(item) }}"
  loop: "{{ data_set_2|map('extract', data_set_1)|list }}"
- debug:
    var: result|to_nice_json
```

give (export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml)

```
  result|to_nice_json: |-
    {
        "field1": "1",
        "field2": "2",
        "field3": "3",
        "field4": "4"
    }
```